# nodejs throwing ENOENT error on file upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

This is my server.js file. I am trying to write a fileupload using native nodejs (without lib). Everytime i try to upload a file, it throws me a weird error. This is a Linux machine.

{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/uploads/lol.txt'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/uploads/lol.txt' }

/uploads/lol.txt is the destination path. Needs serious help.

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
    //qs = require('querystring');
var port = 9000, server, data;

data = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

server = http.createServer(function(req , res) {
  switch(req.url) {
    case "/":
        __serverResponse(res);
        break;
    case "/upload":
        __handleUpload(req, res);
        break;
    default:
        __serverResponse(res);
        break;
  }
});

function __handleUpload(req, res) {
    var __bufferData = __contentLength = 0;

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      __bufferData += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
      //write contents to a file
      fs.writeFile('/uploads/lol.txt', __bufferData, function(err) {
        if (err)
          return console.log(err);
    });

    //end response with 200 OK
    //Modularize __serverResponse code
    res.end();
  });   
}

function __serverResponse(res) {
  res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
}

function startServer() {
  server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening at port '+ port);
  });
}

function closeServer() {
  server.close();
}

module.exports = {
  start: startServer,
  end: closeServer
};

This is the HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="simple-form" action='/upload' method='POST'>
            <label for='file-input'> Select file </label>
            <input type='file' id='file-input' name='file-name'/>
            <input type='submit'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/uploads/lol.txt` is an absolute file path.  Try just using `uploads/lol.txt` to make it relative to the root directory of your application.